# Cronjob like python script

Tags: python, background

I have this python script

```
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Alarmanlagen-Steuerung')
parser.add_argument('--HOME', help='Heim-Modus', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--SOS', help='Heim-Modus', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--AWAY', help='Heim-Modus', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--UNLOCK', help='Heim-Modus', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--SILENT', help='Heim-Modus', action='store_true')
...

if args.SOS :
    #do something
elif args.HOME :
    #do something
```

How can i start this script like this:

```
alarmAnlage.py --HOME #start this script at 23:00 and cancel it at 06:30
alarmAnlage.py --UNLOCK #start this script at 06:30 and cancel it at 23:00
```

I want to run "alarmAnlage.py --HOME" in background, then cancel it and run "alarmAnlage.py --UNLOCK" and so on...

Comment: One way to build this would be to have two executables: A daemon that runs continuously, and a script that signals it to enter different states (possibly by sending it a [UNIX signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) or communicating over a socket)

Comment: So, i should make an "bdaemon.py" as background daemon, and this daemon should start and stop "alarmAnlage.py --HOME" ? Or do you have some hints for me?

Comment: Or should be alarmAnlage.py as the daemon, and dcontroller.py as the controller for alarmAnlage.py?

Comment: Yeah, the second one.